# How to Set Client Dependency of CSS and JS files in Asp.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've often to include CSS and JS files as required by the plugins I use in every page. So I want to centralize all those dependencies in a single place in my app. thus if a dependency for a given plug-in is changed or updated, I'll only have to modify a single place in my app.

Comment: Any framework for managing CSS & JavaScript dependencies and optimizations for our web application..?

Comment: "use bundles" doesn't answer the question, which is how to manage the dependencies, not how to combine or compress files, which is what bundling does.